# OSX keeps switching to the first space

Tags: macos, spaces

I use spaces with 10.9. I run a few applications in full screen mode. While focused on an application in full screen mode every minute or so I switched back to the first space. This happens with no input on my behalf.

I suspected it was an application in the background taking focus. I shut down all applications that do this and have also disabled space switching on application focus. After a reset the issue persists.

I noticed that the tool bar glitches out after the switch happens. It feels like a bug because when the application is not in full screen mode the icons on my desktop will disappear for a split second and then reappear. This seems to be happening with the same frequency as the space switching issue. Has anyone en-counted this? Is there a fix? It's driving me nuts!

Comment: This article maybe of interest http://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-google-drive-crashing-finder-in-mavericks/

Comment: I had the same issue happening to me, but I had Google Drive uninstalled already (pre-mavericks upgrade). But just in case someone else is in the same situation as I am, this only seemed to be happening to me while Microsoft Word 2011 was open.

Comment: @BrDaHa: I have the same issue as you have. The switching is caused by Word for me. Did you find any way to solve it? It is very irritating... I even did a clean reinstall of OSX yesterday, to no avail.

Comment: As this is solved, I can't add an answer so a comment will do. My issue was caused by a dialog box in screen #3 of outlook in screen #1. Find the screen that triggers the switch and look for it there. But to do that, you need to move the offending app to it first.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This seems to be Google Drive-related. The behavior has stopped after quitting Google Drive app (in the taskbar).

If you have the same issue, please also report to the **Google Support Forums** so Google will know the extent of the issue: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/report-a-problem/sv-ZC0ws3Mw

This is now fixed -
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/drive/report-a-problem/kqdqmoMWtk8

Comment: Google Drive may cause this, but is not the only one causing this. I do not have Google Drive and suffer from this all day long. My issue seems to be Java related as it happens when I build projects using Maven with Java either in my IDE or command line. If either IDE or iterm2 is full screened it will keep jumping back to the first desktop screen.

Comment: It seems to me that apple should build a more robust dashboard. I have the same problem with and without google drive app. This is still happening. I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: This happens to me  at OSX 12.2.1 and i don't have google drive installed at all