# Finder windows keeps turning off and on

Tags: finder, imac, macos, crash

All of a sudden my Finder windows keeps disappearing and reappearing every 30 seconds or so. I restarted the computer, and emptied the trash can as some Google search suggested, but none of them worked. Any ideas? I was just browsing the web, wasn't installing/uninstalling anything.

BTW, it's a 2010 iMac with Mavericks.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing on one of my Mac's (Mac Pro 2008 - Mavericks with Server). It is making the machine unusable as I keep getting brought back to the desktop when in full screen apps. Can't copy anything off drives etc (even remote connections disappear at the same time)

Comment: This question seems to be related http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/108333/osx-keeps-switching-to-the-first-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved it on my side, are you running Google Drive? If so, turn it off and the problem goes away. I did so on my machine and it was back to normal, the moment I started Google Drive, the Finder Windows flashed again.

You can see more people with same issue on the [Apple Discussion forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5525710?tstart=0)

Comment: Yes, I found that too. That is the problem! Come on Google!

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue as well. Google Drive was syncing 1.5GB file to my computer, and Finder started to crash every minute or so. Didn't know what to do until this answer... Restarted Google Drive once it finished downloading, and the issue went away.

Comment: Or, you can keep gdrive and turn off the 'visualize status icons' (or something like..) preference

Answer (score 0):

I had to kill off Finder preferences and reboot, then I was good to go:

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
rm -rf com.apple.finder.plist com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
```